# Black-Scholes formula for Poisson jumps

Tags: black-scholes, derivatives, poisson, jump-diffusion

For underlying asset
$$d S = r S dt + \sigma S d W + (J-1)Sd N$$
here $W$ is a Brownian motion, $N(t)$ is Poisson process with intensity $\lambda.$

Suppose $J$ is log-normal with standard deviation $\sigma_J,$ denote
$$k = E[J-1]$$
then the value of vanilla call is
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\lambda'\tau)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda'\tau}V_{BS}(S,t;\sigma_n,r_n)$$
Here
$$\lambda' = \lambda(1+k),\ \tau =T - t$$
$$\sigma^2_n = \sigma^2 + \dfrac{n\sigma_J^2}{\tau},\ 
 r_n=r-\lambda k+\dfrac{n\log(1+k)}{\tau}$$
and $V_{BS}$ is Black-Scholes value of a call without jumps.

The result seems to be the weighted mean of vanilla calls, but how to deduce this conclusion? Or is there any reference?

Suppose $\log J \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2_J)$ and $Z$ is standard normal, then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log S_T &=& \log S_0 + (r - \dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T + \sigma\sqrt{T} Z + N(T)\log(J)\\
&\sim& \log S_0 + \dfrac{1}{2}N(T)\sigma_J^2  +N(T)\mu + (r - \dfrac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}^2)T + \hat{\sigma}\sqrt{T}Z\\
&=& \log \hat{S}_0 + (r - \dfrac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}^2)T + \hat{\sigma}\sqrt{T} Z 
\end{eqnarray*}
we omit the representations of $\hat{S}_0,\ \hat{\sigma}.$ So I think the price at $0$ should be
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda T}V_{BS}(\hat{S}_0,0;\hat{\sigma}_n,r)$$

Why the author change the risk free rate  $r_n$ and intensity $\lambda',$ does he change the measure for both Brownian motion and Poisson process?

Comment: See [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33560/formula-for-merton-jump-diffusion-call-price/33565#33565).

Comment: Looks like the Merton model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formula for Merton jump diffusion call price](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33560/formula-for-merton-jump-diffusion-call-price)

Comment: please see the update @Gordon

Comment: pls see the update @LocalVolatility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We assume that the process $\{J_t, \, t\ge 0\}$ is defined at the jump times of the Poisson process $\{N_t, \, t \ge 0\}$, and all the jump sizes are independent and identically distributed. That is,
\begin{align*}
Q_t \equiv \int_0^t (J_t-1) dN_t = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} (J_i-1),
\end{align*}
where $J_i$, for $i=1, \ldots, \infty$, are independent and $\xi_i = \ln J_i \sim N\left(u, \sigma_J^2\right)$.
Note that, the process
\begin{align*}
Q_t -\lambda k\, t
\end{align*}
is a martingale.
Moreover, as the discount stock price process $\{e^{-rt}S_t, \ t\ge 0\}$ is a martingale,  under the risk-neutral measure, we assume that the stock price process $\{S_t, \, t \ge 0\}$ satisfies an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t \Big[(r-\lambda k)dt + \sigma dW_t + dQ_t\Big].
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
S_T &= e^{\left(r-\lambda k-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma W_T} \prod_{i=1}^{N_T} J_i = e^{\left(r-\lambda k-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma W_T + \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} \xi_i}.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $n\ge 0$,
\begin{align*}
S_T\, \mathbb{I}_{N_T=n} &=e^{\left(r-\lambda k + \frac{n u}{T}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma W_T + \sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_i-u)}\\
&=e^{\left(r-\lambda k + \frac{n u}{T}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sqrt{\sigma^2 + \frac{n \sigma_J^2}{T}}\sqrt{T} Z}\\
&=e^{\left(r_n -\frac{1}{2}\sigma_n^2\right)T + \sigma_n \sqrt{T} Z},
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, $\sigma_n= \sqrt{\sigma^2 + \frac{n \sigma_J^2}{T}}$, and
\begin{align*}
r_n &= r-\lambda k + \frac{n u}{T}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_n^2\\
&= r-\lambda k + \frac{n\ln(1+k)}{T}.
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT}E\left((S_T-K)^+ \right) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-rT}E\left((S_T-K)^+ \mathbb{I}_{N_T=n}\right)P(N_T=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{(-r+r_n)T}e^{-r_nT}E\left((S_T-K)^+ \mathbb{I}_{N_T=n}\right)P(N_T=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda T}e^{(-r+r_n)T}C(S_0, K, r_n, \sigma_n, T)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda T}e^{\left(-\lambda k + \frac{n\ln(1+k)}{T}\right)T}C(S_0, K, r_n, \sigma_n, T)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda T)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda(1+k) T}e^{\left(-\lambda k + \frac{n\ln(1+k)}{T}\right)T}C(S_0, K, r_n, \sigma_n, T)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda' T)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda' T}C(S_0, K, r_n, \sigma_n, T),
\end{align*}
where $\lambda'=(1+k)\lambda$ and $C(S_0, K, r_n, \sigma_n, T)$ is the Black-Scholes option price.

Comment: Thanks a lot, why here is $d S = S_t\left((r- \lambda k)d t +\sigma d W + (J-1)d N_t\right)$? Under the original measure, I think it should be $d S = S_t\left((r+ \lambda k)d t +\sigma d W + ((J-1)d N_t -  \lambda kd t\right) $

Comment: If you already have it in the end, you don't need it at the drift to have the martinaglity.

Comment: but the given condition of $dS$ on the top have no $\lambda kdt$ in both $d N$ and $r,$ then the result should not be the given one. And I think $dS$ should write as $dS =S(rdt + \sigma(dW + \dfrac{\lambda k}{\sigma}dt) + ((J-1)dN - \lambda kdt),$ then change the measure. But we can no longer obtain the representation of $r_n$ bove.

Comment: Sorry, I think my deduction is right, and after  changing the measure, we have your representation of $dS.$ The last question  is the method in my update not right? Since the discounted value of $S$ is not martingale, and we can't simple replace by $\hat{S}$ and $\hat{\sigma}.$

Comment: You can still work with the original process you provided and calculate the option price in a mathematical sense. However, note that, as $e^{-rt}S_t$ is not a martingale, the term $-\lambda k$ has to be added to the drifted to make it appropriate.

Comment: @A.Oreo: Yes, you can use the change measure technique to get the correct form.

Comment: How did you deduce this:
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t \Big[(r-\lambda k)dt + \sigma dW_t + dQ_t\Big].
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
S_T &= e^{\left(r-\lambda k-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma W_T} \prod_{i=1}^{N_T} J_i = e^{\left(r-\lambda k-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma W_T + \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} \xi_i}.
\end{align*}
The $$\prod_{i=1}^{N_T} J_i $$ factor how did it come here?

Comment: It is based Ito's lemma for jump processes.

Comment: I mean why: $$d ( \sum_{i=1}^{N_{t}} (J_{i}-1)) = \log(J_{i})dN_{t}$$

Comment: I do not think that is employed in my derivation. Do you mean $d\sum_{n=1}^{N_t} (J_i-1) = (J_t-1)dN_t$?

Comment: check page 9 in this pdf: http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/LocalStochasticJumpDiffusion.pdf

Comment: the last term in the first line of equation (24) should be $\log(Y_{i})$ not $(Y_{t}-1)$. So why it's $(Y_{t}-1)$?

Comment: You might mixed $S_t$ and $\ln S_t$. This discussion is already long enough. Please ask another question, or provide another solution.

Comment: I found my answer. You were right. Cont and Tankov (2004) give the Itô formula for the jump-diffusion process (which is different from Ito formula without the jump process). After that it's straightforward application. Thanks anyways. It was written in the pdf file that I mentioned up (theorem 2).